Can we change the color of required field box to any other color other than red?
Is there a way to override the error border color for required field to any other color, I have a requirement to change the error box color and error text color. I'm able to change the error text color but not the box color. Any suggestions please?


Due to Shadow DOM, which ensures CSS isolation, your CSS won't leak into child component. You can only modify that style via styling hooks setting --slds-g-color-error-base-40 property, which works for both the error text and the border.
Just assign a class to your HTML element in order to limit the override of that property, then set it into the CSS file, i.e.
HTML
<lightning-input
    required
    class="purple"
    label="Custom Error Color">
</lightning-input>

CSS
:host .purple {
    --slds-g-color-error-base-40: purple;
}

Output:

This example is valid for both lightning-input and lightning-input-field.

Thanks for your response @RubenDG, Also, is there a way to remove the border color and display only text? I have not marked this field as required but throwing error from reportValidity(). I need to display only text in pink and not the border. Any way to get this?

@sfdcDev no, sorry, they share the same property. You could build your own component starting from blueprint
